# What is causing the Mover to fall off the screen?

Tags: java, processing

Adding the "force of gravity" causes the object to eventually disappear

I honestly can't find the bug.

Mover class

```java
class Mover {
  PVector acc;
  PVector loc;
  PVector vel;

  Mover() {
    loc = new PVector(width/2, height/2);
    vel = new PVector(0, 0);
    acc = new PVector(0, 0);
  }

  void update() {

    // Mouse
    //PVector mouse = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);
    //mouse.sub(loc);
    //mouse.setMag(0.5);

    //F = M * A
    vel.add(acc);
    loc.add(vel);
    vel.limit(2);
  }

  void gravity() {
    PVector grav = new PVector(0, 9.8);

    acc.add(grav);
  }

  void wind(float wind_){
    PVector wind = new PVector(wind_,0);
    acc.add(wind);
  }
  void display() {
    stroke(0);
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    ellipse(loc.x, loc.y, 20, 20);
  }

  void bounce() {
    if ((loc.x > width) || (loc.x < 0)) {
      vel.x *= -1;
      acc.x *= -1;
    }
    if ((loc.y > height) || (loc.y < 0)) {
      vel.y *= -1;
      acc.y *= -1;
    }
  }

  void edges() {
    if (loc.x > width) {
      loc.x = 0;
    } else if (loc.x < 0) {
      loc.x = width;
    }
    if (loc.y > height) {
      loc.y = 0;
    } else if (loc.y < 0) {
      loc.y = height;
    }
  }
}
```

Main file

```java
Mover b;


void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  b = new Mover();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  b.gravity();
  b.wind(0.5);
  b.update();
  b.bounce();
  //b.edges();

  b.display();
}
```

I expect the ball to eventually rest at the bottom of the screen

What I get is it eventually disappearing.

Also the new helper to make posting easier is making me add more to this question, but what I said is literally all I have to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a collision withe the ground or ceiling is detected, then you have to limit the position of the ball to the bounds of the window:

```java
class Mover {

    // [...]

    void bounce() {

        // [...]

        if ((loc.y > height) || (loc.y < 0)) {
            vel.y *= -1;
            acc.y *= -1;
            loc.y = loc.y > height ? height : 0; // limit y in the range [0, height]
        }
    }
}
```

Since the gravity is continuously added to the acceleration vector (`b.gravity();`), the ball will slightly go to no where, if the position is below the ground. Note, if the velocity vector (`vel`) is to small to lift the ball above the ground, then the condition `loc.y > height` is fulfilled again and the acceleration is turned towards again by `acc.y *= -1`.

---

An option would be to fix the method edges:

```java
class Mover {

    // [...]

    void edges() {
        if (loc.x > width) {
            loc.x = width;
        } else if (loc.x < 0) {
            loc.x = 0;
        }
        if (loc.y > height) {
            loc.y = height;
        } else if (loc.y < 0) {
            loc.y = 0;
        }
    }
```

And to limit the position of the ball by calling `b.edges()` in draw():

```java
void draw() {
    background(255);

    b.wind(0.5);
    b.gravity();
    b.update();
    b.bounce();
    b.edges();

    b.display();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Would it work if i just added the edges class to the bounce class? Making a bounds class?

Comment: @CameronCampos You've to fix the method  `edges`. See the 2nd part of the answer, which I've added right now.